# How to make a function that takes two sets with strings that returns the equivalent values? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, set, equals

//EDIT: I'm using Codehs for this problem and it doesn't use filter or has'

function start(){

```
var gifts = ["book","car"]; 

var presents = ["game","book"];

 var tim = new Set();

 var sally = new Set();

tim.add(gifts);

sally.add(presents);

  var ans = compare(tim,sally);

  println(ans);

//should print in "book"
}

function compare(first,second){
//code here
}
```

I have tried looping over the elements and using union
`set.union();`. I don't know where to approach the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Have you even bothered googling this? Even the MDN page for `Set` has an example to do exactly this!

Comment: It might be easier to google by the more correct name of the operation "intersection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you're looking for items that are members of both sets, that's called the set [*intersection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)), not the set [*union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)).

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Iterating_Sets) has some examples of various set operations, including an intersection:

```
var intersection = new Set([...set1].filter(x => set2.has(x)));
```

Here's how you could use it your code:

```js
var compare = (a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(x => b.has(x)));

var gifts = new Set(["book", "car"]);
var presents = new Set(["game", "book"]);
var ans = compare(gifts, presents);

console.log(...ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the contents of a set with `filter()` and `has(). But first you need to get the data into the sets properly.

This (sadly) isn't going to work:

```
tim.add(gifts);
```

because it will add the whole array as a single set element. You can only do that when you create the set:

```
var tim = new Set(gifts);
```

```js
function start(){

    var gifts = ["book","car"]; 
    var presents = ["game","book"];   
    var tim = new Set(gifts);
    var sally = new Set(presents);
    
    var ans = compare(tim,sally);
    
    console.log(ans);
    
    }
    
function compare(first,second){
    return [...first].filter(item => second.has(item))
}
start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get an array of items of the first set and filter it by taking `Set` prototype method `has` with the Set itself.

Basically this

```
[...first].filter(Set.prototype.has, second)
    ^^^^^                                    the Set
 ^^^                                         take Set as iterable
^        ^                                   into array
           ^^^^^^                            filter the array
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          by borrowing a method of Set
                                     ^^^^^^  with a Set
```

is converting a Set `first` to an array and takes [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with `thisArg` as second parameter.

```js
function compare(first, second) {
    return [...first].filter(Set.prototype.has, second);
}

var gifts = ["book", "car"],
    presents = ["game", "book"],
    tim = new Set(gifts),
    sally = new Set(presents);

console.log(compare(tim, sally));
```